# Find parent "SVG" element in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

```js
var HELPERS = {
  getElem: function($this) {
    return HELPERS.findAncestor($this, "svg");
  },
  findAncestor: function (el, sel) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
    console.log(!el ? "Not found" : "Found");
    return el;
  },
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <svg height="150" width="500">
    <ellipse onclick="HELPERS.getElem(this)" cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:purple" />
    <ellipse onclick="HELPERS.getElem(this)" cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:lime" />
    <ellipse onclick="HELPERS.getElem(this)" cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15" style="fill:yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. 
  </svg>
</div>
```

As you can observe, this works in modern browsers, unfortunately I need IE11 support. I have tried different findAncestor functionality (e.g. using .closest polyfill) with no luck.

Anything that can help me solve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a problem to resolve that you can't quite figure out with the code written as it is. May I suggest you refactor the `while` loop so it is not so abstract and magic with cryptic side effects? Then the problem _may_ be obvious to you or easier to fix.

Comment: parentNode instead of parentElement for IE I think.

Comment: Thanks guys. Getting closer, yes `parentElement` was part of the problem. Now I need to find an alternative for `matches || matchesSelector` for svg in IE.

Comment: Consider reading [the mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). It even contains how to polyfill the method for non-supported browsers. --- The article says that `matches` is supported on IE11...

Comment: Thanks guys, seems to work now

Answer (score 1):

All SVG DOM elements have a property called `ownerSVGElement`. It points at the closest ancestor `<svg>` element.  I have checked that this is also supported by IE11. So the following should work.

```
var HELPERS = {
  getElem: function($this) {
    return $this.ownerSVGElement;
  }
}
```

This assumes, of course, that you don't need the `findAncestor()` method somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Cumulation of the comments, I have came up with this solution.

1. Use `parentNode` if `parentElement` doesn't exist.
2. Add `.matches` polyfill

```
(import .matches polyfill here)

var HELPERS = {
  getElem: function($this) {
    return HELPERS.findAncestor($this, "svg");
  },
  findAncestor: function (el, sel) {
    if (typeof el.closest === "function") {
      return el.closest(sel) || null;
    }
    while ((el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
    return el;
  },
 }
```

`.matches` polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Polyfill

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.